# Is there a library "SKPSMTPMessage" for Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, skpsmtpmessage

Is there any SKPSMTPMessage library to use in Swift? [earlier i have used this tutorial which is in objective - c](http://iosameer.blogspot.in/2013/01/sending-e-mail-in-background-from-ios_25.html). What I want to do is send a mail in background using Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any email sending library in Swift, but you can definitely use the one described in the Objective-C tutorial in your Swift application. All Objective-C libraries are cross-compatible with Swift code: just use a [`bridging header`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

Answer (score 3):

Simply integrate skpsmtpmessage with cocoa pods by adding:

```
pod 'skpsmtpmessage'
```

to your Podfile and then this is how you send an email from code:

```
import skpsmtpmessage

class MailSender: NSObject, SKPSMTPMessageDelegate {
    static let shared = MailSender()

    func sendEmail(subject: String, body: String) {
        let message = SKPSMTPMessage()
        message.relayHost = "smtp.gmail.com"
        message.login = "login@gmail.com"
        message.pass = "password"
        message.requiresAuth = true
        message.wantsSecure = true
        message.relayPorts = [587]
        message.fromEmail = "login@gmail.com"
        message.toEmail = "to@gmail.com"
        message.subject = subject
        let messagePart = [kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey: body]
        message.parts = [messagePart]
        message.delegate = self
        message.send()
    }

    func messageSent(_ message: SKPSMTPMessage!) {
        print("Successfully sent email!")
    }

    func messageFailed(_ message: SKPSMTPMessage!, error: Error!) {
        print("Sending email failed!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Its crashing the application, please let me know if you have also faced crash issue?

Comment: No, I did not had any crashes last time I used this (in Feb 2018).