# Sending Mailcore2 Plain Emails in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, api, mailcore2, mailcore

I've recently incorporated MailCore2 into my Objective-C project, and it has worked perfectly. Now, I am in the process of transitioning the code within the app to Swift. I have successfully imported the MailCore2 API into my swift project, but I see no documentation (Google search, libmailcore.com, github) on how to turn the following working Objective-C code into Swift Code:

```
MCOSMTPSession *smtpSession = [[MCOSMTPSession alloc] init];
smtpSession.hostname = @"smtp.gmail.com";
smtpSession.port = 465;
smtpSession.username = @"matt@gmail.com";
smtpSession.password = @"password";
smtpSession.authType = MCOAuthTypeSASLPlain;
smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionTypeTLS;

MCOMessageBuilder *builder = [[MCOMessageBuilder alloc] init];
MCOAddress *from = [MCOAddress addressWithDisplayName:@"Matt R"
                                              mailbox:@"matt@gmail.com"];
MCOAddress *to = [MCOAddress addressWithDisplayName:nil 
                                            mailbox:@"hoa@gmail.com"];
[[builder header] setFrom:from];
[[builder header] setTo:@[to]];
[[builder header] setSubject:@"My message"];
[builder setHTMLBody:@"This is a test message!"];
NSData * rfc822Data = [builder data];

MCOSMTPSendOperation *sendOperation = 
   [smtpSession sendOperationWithData:rfc822Data];
[sendOperation start:^(NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error sending email: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Successfully sent email!");
    }
}];
```

Does anyone know how to successfully send an email in Swift using this API? Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

**Step 1)** Import mailcore2, I'm using cocoapods

```
pod 'mailcore2-ios'
```

**Step 2)** Add mailcore2 to your bridging header: Project-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import <MailCore/MailCore.h>
```

**Step 3)** Translate to swift

```
var smtpSession = MCOSMTPSession()
smtpSession.hostname = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtpSession.username = "matt@gmail.com"
smtpSession.password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
smtpSession.port = 465
smtpSession.authType = MCOAuthType.SASLPlain
smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.TLS
smtpSession.connectionLogger = {(connectionID, type, data) in
    if data != nil {
        if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
            NSLog("Connectionlogger: \(string)")
        }
    }
}

var builder = MCOMessageBuilder()
builder.header.to = [MCOAddress(displayName: "Rool", mailbox: "itsrool@gmail.com")]
builder.header.from = MCOAddress(displayName: "Matt R", mailbox: "matt@gmail.com")
builder.header.subject = "My message"
builder.htmlBody = "Yo Rool, this is a test message!"

let rfc822Data = builder.data()
let sendOperation = smtpSession.sendOperationWithData(rfc822Data)
sendOperation.start { (error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog("Error sending email: \(error)")
    } else {
        NSLog("Successfully sent email!")
    }
}
```

**Note** 
You might be needing a special app password for your google account. See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: @Rool Paap Have you done this with `use_frameworks!` flag in the `Podfile` instead of going with the bridging header way? I tried that but it gives me a **No such module** error when trying to import it like so `import MailCore`.

Comment: When I wrote this, I was still targeting iOS7. So I didn't use use_frameworks!. But let me see what I can do.

Comment: Got the same 'No such module' error, couldn't find a solution. My cocoapods knowledge is limited. Sorry.

Comment: Quick side note if you're using MailCore, sometimes gmail may prevent logging in, then you have to go to your gmail account and enable [this](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) setting.

Comment: @RoolPaap I used your code but I'm stilling get the error about credentials , you can see it in my question here please 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982176/error-when-im-using-mailcore2-in-swift-2

Comment: This works great.  the question I have is in htmlBody.  I am trying to put in the contents of textFields - one per line., how do I insert a line in the html body?

Comment: I no longer use this Library to send mail, but previous versions of my app were approved.

Comment: Top. This solutions is the fastest and the most reliable I found over the net :D

Comment: If for some reason this does not work for you then you can alternatively use other library skpsmtpmessage as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250101/is-there-a-library-skpsmtpmessage-for-swift/48564615#48564615

Comment: @RoolPaap is it possible to read emails from inbox in Swift app using MailCore from different providers like gmail, icloud etc?

Answer (score 7):

**For Swift 3 just copy this**

```
    let smtpSession = MCOSMTPSession()
    smtpSession.hostname = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtpSession.username = "sanipcr7@gmail.com"
    smtpSession.password = "xxxxxxx"
    smtpSession.port = 465
    smtpSession.authType = MCOAuthType.saslPlain
    smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.TLS
    smtpSession.connectionLogger = {(connectionID, type, data) in
        if data != nil {
            if let string = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
                NSLog("Connectionlogger: \(string)")
            }
        }
    }

    let builder = MCOMessageBuilder()
    builder.header.to = [MCOAddress(displayName: "Rool", mailbox: "sanipcr7@gmail.com")]
    builder.header.from = MCOAddress(displayName: "Matt R", mailbox: "matt@gmail.com")
    builder.header.subject = "My message"
    builder.htmlBody = "Yo Rool, this is a test message!"

    let rfc822Data = builder.data()
    let sendOperation = smtpSession.sendOperation(with: rfc822Data!)
    sendOperation?.start { (error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("Error sending email: \(error)")
        } else {
            NSLog("Successfully sent email!")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bro I am getting an Error saying "A stable connection could not be established" in the console

Comment: @VenkateshChejarla,
I am also getting same error.

Error : Error sending email: Optional(Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=1 "A stable connection to the server could not be established." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=A stable connection to the server could not be established.})

Comment: Does Anyone have solution for this error? #help me.

Answer (score 4):

To send an image as attachment in swift just add:

```
    var dataImage: NSData?
    dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6)!
    var attachment = MCOAttachment()
    attachment.mimeType =  "image/jpg"
    attachment.filename = "image.jpg"
    attachment.data = dataImage
    builder.addAttachment(attachment)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would've added this in the comments below the answer but there are so many.

The steps in the accepted answer worked especially using the link to the special app password for your google account.

But @RoolPaap used a different bridging header then the one I did. I used `#include "Mailcore.h"`

I followed this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkpLqNN8xtU&t=32s:)

```
#ifndef MyProjectName_Bridging_Header_h
#define MyProjectName_Bridging_Header_h

#include "Mailcore.h"

#endif /* MyProjectName_Bridging_Header_h */
```